# what animation/painting software they used in this youtube channel?

Tags: animation, youtube

my daughter saw the painting animation on this youtube art channel and she loved it!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jCMPerCWfcw&t=53s

Now she wants me to learn the application that they used so I can make this exact type of painting/animation videos for her at home the way that she wants!! hahaha

what is that software? is it hard to learn? is it only one software that they use for the whole painting, animation and adding music to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the exact package but I would suggest taking a look at [Krita](https://krita.org/en/features/highlights/) & at [TuxPaint](http://www.tuxpaint.org/screenshots/).

TuxPaint is specifically aimed at 3-12 year old artists and has a number of starter pictures to colour in.

[image]

While Krita is aimed at a more advanced group:

[image]

**Both are free & cross platform so no issues with giving them a go!**